# Inserting CSV to MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I would like to insert a CSV to MySQL. How can I only update my table if the column `sha1` is existing in MySQL table? If the column `sha1` was exist, insert it.

**I have this code to insert csv:**

```
while(($csvdata = fgetcsv($handle,10000,","))!== FALSE){
    if($i>0) {
        $sha1 = $csvdata[0];
        $vsdt = $csvdata[1];
        $trendx  = $csvdata[2];
        $notes  = $csvdata[3];

        $sql = "INSERT INTO jeremy_table_trend (date_sourced,sha1,vsdt,trendx,notes) VALUES ('$date','$sha1','$vsdt','$trendx','$notes')";
        $query = mysqli_query($con , $sql);

        $c = $c+1;
        error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
    }
    $i++;
    error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
}
```

Comment: Don't format SQL with parameters, use a prepared statement and pass in the parameters, this will take care of escaping and formatting the parameters  correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this, This may help you

```
<?php
while(($csvdata = fgetcsv($handle,10000,","))!== FALSE){
    if($i>0) {
        $sha1 = $csvdata[0];
        $vsdt = $csvdata[1];
        $trendx  = $csvdata[2];
        $notes  = $csvdata[3];

        // Get record where sha1 
        $check_sha = "SELECT sha1 FROM jeremy_table_trend WHERE sha1='".$sha1."'";
        $check_shaquery = mysqli_query($con , $check_sha);
        if($check_shaquery){
            $sha_count = mysqli_num_rows($check_shaquery);
        }

        // Check if sha1 already in database
        if(isset($sha_count) && $sha_count>0){
            $sql = "UPDATE `jeremy_table_trend` SET `date_sourced`='".$date."',`sha1`='".$sha1."',`vsdt`='".$vsdt."',`trendx`='".$trendx."',`notes`='".$notes."' WHERE sha1='".$sha1."'";
            $query = mysqli_query($con , $sql);
        }else{
            $sql = "INSERT INTO jeremy_table_trend (date_sourced,sha1,vsdt,trendx,notes) VALUES ('$date','$sha1','$vsdt','$trendx','$notes')";
            $query = mysqli_query($con , $sql);
        }

        $c = $c+1;
        error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
    }
    $i++;
    error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
}
?>
```

Comment: Please be aware that this code is prone to SQL injections and very bad coding style all around.

Answer (score 1):

Please, this is 2018. No need for procedural low-level code anymore. Take a look at a library like [Spout](https://packagist.org/packages/box/spout) to read CSV and use [PDO](https://php.net/pdo) for object-oriented access to the database.

I assume the column `sha1` has a `UNIQUE` index set? If not, it should. Then you can do this in one neat SQL statement with the [INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) syntax:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO jeremy_table_trend (date_sourced,sha1,vsdt,trendx,notes) VALUES ('$date','$sha1','$vsdt','$trendx','$notes') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE";
```

In addition to checking for the existence of an entry with the same hash in the database, you could also use an ORM layer that will take care of this for you.

Comment: What's the error message? Did you set the UNIQUE index on the column "sha1"? It needs to have the index for the query to work.